# Cant access control pattern of controlType.Text nested in DataGrid/DataItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to select a row in a controlType.dataGrid using System.Windows.Automation. Row is a controlType.Text. I tried to search for any way how to get its pattern and invoke pattern.Select() function, but with no success. Can anyone give me a Hint how to do it? Thanks

Selecting DataGrid:

```
AutomationElement dataGrid = routeDetailOpt.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "m_RouteListView"));
```

Selecting row itself:

```
AutomationElement rowToSelect = dataGrid.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.DataItem));
```

Selecting "cell" so that i can obtain its pattern and invoke Select():

```
AutomationElement rowHeader = rowToSelect.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Text));
```

Obtaining pattern:

```
SelectionItemPattern pattern = rowHeader.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as SelectionItemPattern;
```

I am getting following error:

""
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in ***.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unsupported Pattern.
""

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after a long struggle we have found the solution.

It turned out, that all we need to do is call "SetFocus()" on a dataGrid item and it all worked just fine! (Don't ask me why it did not have Focus from the begining)

Just FYI, i used rowToSelect for actual selection, not rowHeader

```
SelectionItemPattern pattern = rowToSelect.GetCurrentPattern(SelectionItemPattern.Pattern) as SelectionItemPattern;
pattern.Select();
```